# Does every object of a class in javascript hold a copy of its functions or just one?

Tags: javascript

Let's say you are creating a video game, you've got multiple game objects and they all have collider objects attached to them. You want to create a function that checks whether or not two colliders have collided. It seems intuitive to place this function into the collider class, but surely that means that every object will carry a copy of this function, meaning redundancy. It seems like it would be better to therefore place a function that checks for collision (and takes two colliders as parameters) into a (probably static) utility class in the global scope. Is this better practice?

Comment: If an object instance does not have its own method with that name, then the prototype object of that class is checked. This means that there is usually only one copy of the method and it lives in the prototype.  It is possible however to put a copy in each instance. It depends on how you design the class.

Comment: You said, you've got multiple game objects and they all have collider objects attached to them. So, in 99 % of all cases, the game objects share a common prototype object. This very prototype object would be regarded as the go-to place to attach the collider checker function to. -- Regards, M.